# Set time series vectors lengths equal (resize/rescale them with use of linear interpolation)

Tags: r, datetime, vector, vectorization

I have huge dataset of time series which are represented as vectors (no time labels available), due to some errors in measuring process their lengths (as values from `length()`  show) varies slightly (~10%) but each of them definitively describs time interval of exacly two minutes. I would like to rescale/resize them and then calculate some statistics between them (so I need time series of equal lengths).

I need vary fast approach and linear interpolation is perfectly good choice for me, because speed is more important.

Simple example, rescaling  vector of length 5 to vector of length of 10 :

```
input <- 0:4 # should be rescaled/resized into :
output <- c(0, .444, .888, 1.333, 1.777, 2.222, 2.666, 3.111, 3.555, 4)
```

I think that the fastest approach is to create matrix `w` ('w' for weights) which dimensions are : `length(output) x length(input)`, so `w %*% input gives output(as matrix object)`, if it is the fastest way, how to create matrices `w` efficiently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be enough:

```
resize <- function (input, len) approx(seq_along(input), input, n = len)$y
```

For example:

```
> resize(0:4, 10)
 [1] 0.0000000 0.4444444 0.8888889 1.3333333 1.7777778 2.2222222 2.6666667 3.1111111 3.5555556 4.0000000

> resize( c(0, 3, 2, 1), 10)
 [1] 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 2.666667 2.333333 2.000000 1.666667 1.333333 1.000000
```